# Javascript cannot access php script ourside of root

Tags: php, ajax, directory

My folder structure:

```
/public
   /css
   /fonts
   /images
   /js
   index.php
/resources
   /configs
   /library
   /scripts
   /templates
```

My issue is validate.js (located in /js) cannot access validate.php (located in /scripts).

```
$.ajax( {

    type: "POST",
    url: "../resources/scripts/validate.php",
```

Thanks!

UPDATE, here is error message:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /resources/scripts/validate.php was not found on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A php script should be able to access it.

Create

/public/cgi/myvalidate.php

with

```
<?php include '../../resources/scripts/validate.php'; ?>
```

and

```
$.ajax( {

    type: "POST",
    url: "cgi/myvalidate.php",
```

or place validate.php in a location that can be publicly accessed.

Comment: I can place validate.php into /public, but the goal was to make sure no one could access files in /scripts.

Comment: @TimNguyenBSM I assumed the goal was something like that, but if validate.php is needed for the goal of making the site work then there are conflicting goals. Given the goals I would just use a include from a php file in a location that ajax can access.

Comment: @TimNguyenBSM Another option would be to create a new validate.php but that defeats the purpose of having a validate.php in scripts at all.

Comment: @TimNguyenBSM Note I've updated the file name so that it shows that validate.php is in scripts and myvalidate.php is in cgi.

Comment: On a side note. Any php that is used to login to a SQL server, and anything that has a password, should also be moved to a secure location and then accessed via includes as required in PHP.

Comment: Does using an include keep code away from potential eyeballs? Additionally, it seems it doesnt prevent execution of the php script, which means I would have to add code to prevent execution correct?

Comment: Nobody can see what is in resources directories because they are not public, so nobody can see the code. However, setting up a private directory is not a cure all for web security. PHP can still access it. So you need to prevent any PHP code from being embeded into user input and prevent users from creating any php files in a directory where they can be excuted.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$.ajax( {

    type: "POST",
    url: "../../resources/scripts/validate.php",
```

Comment: Same issue. Cannot access.

Comment: What is the path for the file where validate.js is being used?

Comment: Path is localhost/public/js/validate.js

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax( {

    type: "POST",
    url: "../resources/scripts/validate.php",
```

Comment: Typo in my question. Just updated. There is no forward slash at front of url.